# Find the name of the Creator of a Survey in Sharepoint

Tags: survey-list

I would like to find the creator/author of some surveys on our sharepoint teamsite. I have full control and can change/delete the surveys ect, but I cant find a way to see the author of the surveys - I need to contact them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way how to find it from Sharepoint UI.

If you have access to server, you can look into Sharepoint Manager on list properties - there is Author property.

Another way (also with need of access to the server) is to run one easy powershell script:

```
(get-spweb http://server/website).Lists["List Title"].Author
```